# Python list to html with no-bracket?

Tags: python

I am making one automatic email sending program with python for my work.
Basically, I need to send customer's list to manager everyday.

What I intended is, make a list for customer's name , make html template and send it.

It is working basically, but I hate those list's bracket.
Also I want to send beautiful list: first passenger in first sentence, second passenger in second sentence, not like every passenger in one sentence with ","

[This is what I can see at this stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWdrb.png)

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

namelist = []

while True:
    name = input("Name:  ")  
    question = int(input("More passenger? Yes=1, No=2  "))
    if question == 1:
        namelist.append(name)
        print(namelist)
        
    elif question == 2:
        namelist.append(name)
        print(namelist)
        ready_question = int(input("Ready to send email? Yes=1, No=2  "))
        if ready_question == 1:
            break
        else:
            continue
    else:
        namelist.append(name)
        print("Press 1 or 2")
        continue

subject = ""
body1 = ""
body2 = ""
body3 = "{}".format(namelist)
    

sender_email = ""
receiver_email = ""
password = ""

message = EmailMessage()
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
message["Subject"] = subject

html = f"""
<html>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <p>{body1}</p>
        <p>{body2}</p>
        <p>{body3}</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

message.add_alternative(html, subtype="html")
context = ssl.create_default_context()

print("Sending Email!")

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())

print("Email Sent")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also I want to send beautiful list: first passenger in first sentence,
> second passenger in second sentence, not like every passenger in one
> sentence with ","

You are doing

```
body3 = "{}".format(namelist)
```

which gives you python's representation of list, you might use `.join` method of `str` instance to get list elements joined by it, for example to use 3 spaces you might do:

```
namelist = ["Able","Baker","Charlie"]
body3 = "   ".join(namelist)
print(body3)
```

output

```
Able   Baker   Charlie
```

Considering that you want names in separate lines and use HTML then I suggest you use `<br>` as separator, that is

```
body3 = "<br>".join(namelist)
```

Comment: Thanks sooooooooooo much!!!